# Error installing Arch Linux in VirtualBox

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, virtualbox, grub

I tried to install Arch Linux in VirtualBox.
Following the guidelines in

> install.txt

I am stuck at the GRUB installation. Here is the screenshot of the current scenario:

[image]

Comment: Why are you using ext2?

Comment: I find it simpler to use systemd-boot as the boot manager and skip GRUB altogether. See [systemd-boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot). You need to enable EFI in the VirtualBox settings (System -> Motherboard -> Enable EFI (special OSes only))

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using an LVM physical drive without partitions and grub refuses to install because it doesn't have an explicit MBR (master boot record).
It happened to me last week using the same install guide. To solve it (in a non elegant way) I created another non LVM virtual drive with only one partition (I used it for /boot, but you can leave it empty) and installed grub on that drive.

Comment: alright! let me try that...thanks for the guidance :)